# How to recover abelian class field theory from Langlands?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, langlands-program

I am reading about the Langlands program (mostly for fun). I am mostly self-taught in algebraic number theory. I have read that one recovers abelian class field theory from Langlands by setting $n=1$ so to speak, and looking at the group $G = GL_1$. However, my question has to do with the details of this statement.

More specifically, given an abelian Galois finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, with Galois group $G = \operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb{Q})$, consider a $1$-dimensional representation:

$$ \sigma: G \to GL_1(\mathbb{C}). $$

By Artin's abelian class field theory (please correct me if I make some wrong statements), there is a positive integer $N_{\sigma}$, and a Dirichlet character:

$$ \chi_{\sigma}: (\mathbb{Z}/N_{\sigma}\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^*, $$

such that, for any unramified prime $p$, we have:

$$ \sigma(\{\operatorname{Fr}_p\}) = \chi_{\sigma}([p]), $$

where $\operatorname{Fr}_p$ denotes the Frobenius element associated to $p$ (and $\{-\}$ denotes the conjugacy class) and $[p]$ denotes the class of $p$ modulo $N_{\sigma}$.

My question is, why is a Dirichlet character (such as the one above) a special case of an automorphic representation of $GL_1$ please? For some reason, this is not so obvious to me.

First of all, should one consider $GL_1$ over the adeles over $\mathbb{Q}$ or over $F$? I suspect it is the adeles over $\mathbb{Q}$. But then, given an unramified prime $p$, how does one define the "local" group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}_p \to \mathbb{C}^*$ associated to $\chi_{\sigma}$?

So my question is really, how are the Dirichlet characters a special case of Hecke's Größencharacters (I love writing the 'esset' ß)?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66500/

Comment: @Watson, I see that it is non-trivial. However, I asked a more elementary question here. So I guess my question is related to that post, but it is more elementary.

Comment: See there for the character $GL_1(\Bbb{A_Q})/GL_1(\Bbb{Q})\to \Bbb{C}^*$ (an automorphic form and automorphic representation) corresponding to a Dirichlet character https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3230897/276986 the local representation is the restriction to $GL_1(\Bbb{Q}_p)\subset GL_1(\Bbb{A_Q})$

Comment: @reuns, thank you! It was not at all obvious. Thank you for your help. Could you please write this as an answer? Or should I just delete this post? I could not easily find the answer online though. I suggest keeping this post. Could you please write a short answer?

Comment: [This short note](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/modseminar/pdf/L11.pdf) is useful for getting all the details

Comment: Thank you Mathmo123. Really helpful notes. My reading project turns out to be much more difficult than I thought. But the topic is nice.

Comment: @Malkoun There is nothing difficult when taking examples and making things concrete, it is just they are making things unnecessary abstract (what is difficult of course is the main theorem of CFT, abelian Galois representation = Hecke character)

Comment: @reuns, do you happen to know of some notes on Langlands containing many examples? I did find Milne's notes on CFT as very concrete, but unfortunately, I don't have enough time to go through them. Are there some notes, more or less Milne's style, with many examples, but a bit more condensed perhaps?