# Dirichlet L-series and Hecke L-series

Tags: l-functions, dirichlet-series, hecke-characters, dirichlet-character

I'm working on L-series (reading Rosen's book Number Theory in Function fields) and i read that Dirichlet $L$-series are supposed to be a special case of Hecke $L$-series, and i can't understand why ?

Comment: Dirichlet characters are the (finite order) Hecke characters of $\Bbb{Q}$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3230897/276986

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand this post

Comment: A Dirichlet character is a periodic completely multiplicative function on the integers. I am showing how to convert it to a continuous homomorphism $\Bbb{A_Q^\times/Q^\times\to C^\times}$, a Hecke character of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Did you make any progress? What is a Hecke character to you?

Comment: I'm working on function fields, i don't have the general definition of a Hecke character : Let $F$ be an effective divisor with support $S \subset S_K$. A character of finite
order on the ray class group modulo $F$ is called a Hecke character modulo $F$

Comment: Then it is immediate that this definition works for number fields and that for $\Bbb{Q}$ it gives the Dirichlet characters, right?

Comment: See http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/heckechar.pdf